# Convert from pairs of list elements to adjacency list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is it possible to convert from a list of pair of elements like this:

```
s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
```

to an adjacency list like this below:

```
{'yellow':['1', '3'], 'blue':['2','4'], 'red':['1']}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it already

Answer (score 3):

Use a defaultdict:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in s:
    d[k].append(v)
```

This will allow you to append items to the lists (elements of the dictionary) as if they were there, and if they are not, they will be created as empty lists for you.

This is not doing anything that could not also be done more manually with:

```
d = {}
for k, v in s:
    if k not in d:
        d[k] = []
    d[k].append(v)
```

Note: if you really want the elements of these lists to be strings, then do:

```
    d[k].append(str(v))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! this is almost what I need, but I also need something like every element in the list of pairs should be a key in the dictionary, For example in `s` 1, 2 , and 4 should be a key in the dictionary with an empty list if they don't have elements.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [groupby function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). Mind that you have to sort the list first.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like:

```
m = {}
for key, value in s:
    m.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer, thanks

```
result = {}

for i in follower_list: 
  result.setdefault(i[0], []).append(i[1])
```

Comment: Possibly a small matter, but you will have to create a new empty list on each iteration, which will end up being discarded if the key already exists. Looks like there was a proposal for a way around this, which was rejected - https://bugs.python.org/issue31240